# How to get coordinates of point knowing distance from x,y and angle?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I have such a problem :

I am given :

- x,y
- $\|a\|$
- $\alpha$
- $\vec{v}$ and $\|v\|$

I need to get the coordinates of point X1Y2.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this fact that for two vector $v=(x_1,x_2),w=(y_1,y_2)$ we can evaluate $v.w$, the dot product of $v$ and $w$, by two ways. They are : $$v.w=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$$ and $$v.w=|v||w|\cos(\alpha)$$

Personally, I prefer @Karolis's answer but we can have an elementary approach according to what was given to us.

- $||a||=\sqrt{(X-X_1)^2-(Y-Y_2)^2}$
- $XX_1+YY_2=vw=||v||.||a||.\cos(\alpha)$

Above system have two equations of two unknowns. As you noted, we have $||a||,||v||,\alpha,X,Y$ so, put the known values and evaluate $X_1,Y_2$. I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this but if I am correct I will have an equation with 2 unknowns, right ?

Comment: @Patryk: Right. But you have a system of equation with 2 unknowns and I think after solving this system, you will get X1 and Y1. Tell me if you have any problem in it. ;-)

Comment: Somehow I can't see the second equation. Can you edit your answer so that it is a bit more clearer :) ?

Comment: @Patryk: Sorry and forgive me for the delay.

Comment: Good job explaining! +1

Answer (score 2):

$$(x_1, y_1) = (x, y) + \frac{a}{\|v\|} \cdot R(\alpha) \cdot \vec{v}$$
Where $R(\alpha)$ is a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: @Patryk: This is a best answer for a fast result.+1 ;-)